# Multiple Instances and Multiple Activities calling the same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three Activities. MainActivity,ActivityB and ActivityC. In activity A and B there are two buttons source and destination in both activities. in Activity C there is a list of data. when button is clicked (either Source or destination) from activity A and B. both Activities are calling Activity C
code for Activity A is following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView source,destination;
Button sendSource,sendDestination,btnTob;
String src,des,activity,checksrc,checkdes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    source=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_rcvDataA);
    destination=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_rcvDataAa);
    sendSource=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendA);
    sendDestination=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendAa);
    btnTob=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_toB);

    sendSource.setText("source");
    sendDestination.setText("destination");
    src=sendSource.getText().toString();
    des=sendDestination.getText().toString();

    activity=getClass().getSimpleName();
    sendSource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent send= new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityC.class);
            send.putExtra("source",src);
            send.putExtra("Activity",activity);
            startActivity(send);
        }
    });
    sendDestination.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent senda= new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityC.class);
            senda.putExtra("destination",des);
            senda.putExtra("Activity",activity);
            startActivity(senda);

        }
    });

    btnTob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent movetoB= new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(movetoB);
            finish();
        }
    });   }}
```

and code for Activity B is

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

TextView sourceB,destinationB;
Button sendSourceB,sendDestinationB;

String src,des,activity,checksrc,checkdes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    sourceB=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_rcvDataB);
    destinationB=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_rcvDataBa);
    sendSourceB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendB);
    sendDestinationB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendDataBa);
    activity=getClass().getSimpleName();

    sendDestinationB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent senda= new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
            senda.putExtra("destination",src);
            senda.putExtra("Activity",activity);
            startActivity(senda);
        }
    });

    sendSourceB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent send= new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
            send.putExtra("source",src);
            send.putExtra("Activity",activity);
            startActivity(send);
        }
    });}}
```

now how to check in activityC which activity is calling this activity and which buttonclicklistener is calling the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the value for determine what value and what activity via `Intent.putExtra()`. Please be remember that you need to set the key as the first parameter for `Intent.putExtra()`, like

```
intent.putExtra(THIS_IS_THE_KEY, THIS_IS_YOUR_VALUE);
```

You need to create something like this:

```
// This is the key for your putExtra
// you need to create this as global variable.
public static final String FROM_KEY = "FROM";
public static final String ACTIVITY_KEY = "ACTIVITY";
public static final boolean IS_FROM_SOURCE = true;

// This is a sample to send data to Activity C
// where the activity caller is B and from source
Intent senda= new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
senda.putExtra(FROM_KEY, IS_FROM_SOURCE);
senda.putExtra(ACTIVITY_KEY,"activity_a");
```

Then in your Activity C, you need to receive the Intent Extra.
You can get the value in Activity `onCreate()`, something like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean from = extras.getBoolean(FROM_KEY);
String act = extras.getString(ACTIVITY_KEY);

// do something here if from activity a
if(act.equals("activity_a")) {
  if(IS_FROM_SOURCE) {
    // do something if from source
  } else {
    // do something if from destination.
  }
} else { // if from activity a
  if(IS_FROM_SOURCE) {
    // do something if from source
  } else {
    // do something if from destination.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much . it really helped me alot. That's a great explanation @ישו אוהב אותך ..

Comment: You're welcome ;). Please set this as accepted answer if this the right answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate` or anytime after that method is called in Activity-C, you should do the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent  != null) {
    String activity = intent.getStringExtra("Activity");
    String src = intent.getStringExtra("source");
    // Do something with those values
}
```

Comment: i did that but it was crashing if i directly go to Activity C instead of going from Activity A or Activity B. i solved this by sending a boolean in putExtras  and on activity C i checked that if boolean was true , activity started by intent by startActivityforResult... else it started by startActivity
@jchunchar